# Prevent RMI Export Exception

Tags: java, registry, rmi

I have a simple client/server program that adds a Server object to the registry in a ServerLauncher class using:

```
try {
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        reg.rebind("ServerObject", new Server());
        System.out.println("Server set up completed.");
    } 
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and then clients get a reference to the RMI object using:

```
Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 1099);
remoteServerObject = (ServerInterface) reg.lookup("Server");
```

The program works fine and clients can successfully connect to the server. However, whenever i launch the ServerLauncher more than once i get the error:

java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

This exception doesn't actually affect the functionality of my program as if a 2nd ServerLauncher throws this exception, the Server object is still in the registry having been put there by the 1st ServerLauncher so clients are still able to connect to the server. 
However, i was wondering if there is a way to prevent this exception from occuring. Shouldn't reg.rebind replace whats on the registry? And therefore it shouldn't matter if port 1099 is already in use? I don't understand why this exception is being thrown

Comment: You get exception on LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099); not on rebind. Check line number in stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        reg.rebind("ServerObject", new Server());
        System.out.println("Server set up completed.");
    } 
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
        reg.rebind("ServerObject", new Server());
        System.out.println("Server already installed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't reg.rebind replace whats on the registry?

It does.

> And therefore it shouldn't matter if port 1099 is already in use?

*Non sequitur.* The exception wasn't thrown by `rebind()`, it was thrown by `createRegistry().`

> I don't understand why this exception is being thrown

Port 1099 was already in use by the Registry in the other JVM, so you couldn't create another Registry.

There is more than one problem here. The `Registry` variable should be static, otherwise it may be garbage-collected. If you want to re-use an existing Registry, just call `LocateRegistry.getRegistry():` something like this:

```
static Registry registry;

try {
    registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
} catch (ExportException exc) {
    registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
}
registry.rebind("ServerObject", new Server());
System.out.println("Server set up completed.");
```